# Get evenly spaced numbers in a range, in C

Tags: c

I am trying to perform an easy calculation without beeing able to figure out the right approach to it: I am trying to obtain a specific amount of `N` values, reading the `step` number from user input, within a certain range included between `min` and `max` also read from the user input. Those `N` values must be evenly spaced between themselves.

For instance, this should be able to produce a set of `N` numbers including the lower range limit and the upper one. I need to use decimal `min` and `max` and integer number of `step`.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double min;
    double max;
    int step;
    double table_array[step];
    table_array[0] = min;

    printf("Enter the minimum value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &min );
    
    printf("Enter the maximum value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &max );
    
    printf("Enter the evenly spaced step value: ");
    scanf("%d", &step );
    
    printf("\n----------------------------------\n");    

    int i;
    int increment;
    for (i = 0; i <= step; i++){
        increment = (max - min) / step;
        table_array[i+1] = table_array[i] + increment;
        while (table_array[i] < max){
            printf("%i %lf\n",i, table_array[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I need to improve the for cycle for sure. Any suggestions? I assume it can be even totally wrong since it is not running, or better yet it is running but not showing the right result

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= step; i++)` => `for (i = 0; i <= max; i+=step)`. Not sure about the `max` and `step` variables usage in your program though, as they seem not to be consistent with their usage.

Comment: What is the expected output is `max - min` is not divisible by `step`?

Comment: So... if you want 3 values between `1` and `2` they should be `1`, `1.5`, and `2`? 4 values: `1`, `1.3333`, `1.66666`, `2`? 5 values: `1`, `1.25`, `1.5`, `1.75`, and `2`?

Comment: `double table_array[step];` attempts to create an array with size `step`, but at this point in the program, step is uninitialized.

Comment: If you are required to output `N` evenly spaced values then the loop should be `for(int i=0; i<N; i++)` but you are also asking the user for the start, end and step, so it's unclear what you want. But if you are supposed to compute the interval: don't. Calculate the actual value from each step, otherwise you magnify any error in the calculations.

Comment: @pmg yes you got it, that is what I need

Comment: So divide the range (`max - min`) by the (number of values - 1) for the `step`... ie `step = (max - min) / (double)(n - 1)` ... then loop `n` times. The final value can be a little larger than the `max` in some cases (like `2.0000000000006541`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need declare an array with specific size. Initially the array size is not valid as `step` will initially have garbage value. then you are trying to print `i` with `%i` need to change that one with `%d`. with your `step` you need to calculate the `increment` only once. and as your `increment` can be `double` number then just make sure that you are using a double type for `increment`. now how i calculate the increment as 2 number must be `min` and `max` then there must be `step >= 2` . suppose `max =20` `min =10` and `step=3` so the numbers will be `10,15,20`. so `increment = (max -min )/(step-1) = 5`. now make some complex case . if `step = 1` then `min` must be equal to `max`. we need to check this case explicitly.  another case if `max < min` then just need to swap them.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  double min;
  double max;
  int step;

  printf ("Enter the minimum value: ");
  scanf ("%lf", &min);

  printf ("Enter the maximum value: ");
  scanf ("%lf", &max);

  printf ("Enter the evenly spaced step value: ");
  scanf ("%d", &step);


  double table_array[step + 5];
  table_array[0] = min;
  printf ("\n----------------------------------\n");
  int i;
  double increment;

  if (max < min){
      double temp;
      temp = min;
      min = max;
      max = temp;
    }
  if (step == 1 && max == min) {
      i = 0;
      printf ("%d %.18lf\n", i, table_array[i]);
    } else {
        increment = (max - min) / (step - 1);
        i = 0;

        printf ("%d %.18lf\n", i, table_array[i]);
        for (i = 1; i < step; i++){
            table_array[i] = table_array[i - 1] + increment;
            printf ("%d %.18lf\n", i, table_array[i]);
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @H.R.Emon. Can I ask you what should I use to obtain more decimal units in the final printf?

Comment: @EmmanuelCrova can you please explain your word? i haven't understood what you are asking for?

Comment: @H.R.Emon write it as a function

Comment: what if user enters only one step

Comment: what if max < min

Comment: @H.R.Emon I mean, the result is now truncated to 6 decimal digits, even if my min and max numbers are 10 decimal digits long. How to have the final array with 10 or more decimal digits?
Let's try for example entering

min: -1.985412365478965411;
max: 1.985412363654789987;
step: 128;

you get:

0 -1.985412;
1 -1.954146;
2 -1.922880;


I would need more decimal digits

Comment: `printf ("%d %.16lf\n", i, table_array[i]);`.  just use `.16` in the middle of `%lf` this will print 16 digit after decimal . or whatever number you would like to

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAPI(min,max,type) do{type tmp; if(min > max) {tmp = max; max = min; min = tmp;}}while(0)

double *getnumbers(double *table, size_t nelements, double max, double min)
{
    double step;
    if(table && nelements > 1 )
    {
        SWAPI(min,max, double);
        step = (max - min) / (nelements - 1);
        for(size_t element = 0; element < nelements; element++, min += step)
        {
            table[element] = min;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        table = NULL;
    }
    return table;
}

void printtable(double *table, size_t num)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("[%zu] = %f\n", i, table[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double numbers[25];
    if(getnumbers(numbers,2,3,6))  printtable(numbers, 2);
    printf("\n");
    if(getnumbers(numbers,15,3,6))  printtable(numbers, 15);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/odscs6

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf, scanf, putchar
#include <float.h>  // FLT_EPSILON
#include <math.h>   // fabs

int isequal(double, double);

int main(void) {
    double min, max, step, nnum;

    printf("Maximum: "), scanf("%lf", &max);        // Get maximum
    printf("Minimum: "), scanf("%lf", &min);        // Get minimum
    if (min > max) {                                // If invalid maximum, handle error
        puts("Maximum cannot be over minimum");
        return 1;                                   // Returning 1 indicates program failure
    }
    printf("Step: "),   scanf("%lf", &step);        // Get step
    nnum = (max - min)/step;
    if (!isequal(nnum, (int) nnum) || step <= 0) {  // If invalid step, handle error
        puts("Invalid step");
        return 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');                                  // Separate input from output
    for (int i = 0; i <= nnum; i++) {
        printf("%d. %lf\n", i + 1, min);
        min += step;                                // We already know it will go into maximum evenly           
    }
    return 0;                                       // Returning 0 indicates program success
}

int isequal(double x, double y) {                   // fabs()      = Float absolute value
    return fabs(x - y) < FLT_EPSILON;               // FLT_EPSILON = Smallest comparable float value    
}
```

Comment: I removed some unnecessary variables and opted for a more simple approach in my answer. Some extra headers such as stdlib and stdbool can be used to increase readability, but this is the bare minimum.